# How to code a flexible numbered table list for DATA MERGE in SAS?

Tags: merge, macros, sas, proc

I have a program that should merge any number of tables numbered consecutively. I tried to use macro variables but to no avail. The error " Missing numeric suffix on a numbered data set list" keeps popping up.

Here is the defective code:

```
DATA INPUTF;
  INPUT DSN $;
  CARDS;
  forum1
  forum2
  forum3
  ;
RUN;

DATA forum1;
  INPUT contact $ forum1 $;
  CARDS;
  Mash HERE
  Greg HERE
  Bob HERE
  ;
PROC SORT DATA=forum1;
  BY contact;
RUN;

DATA forum2;
  INPUT contact $ forum2 $;
  CARDS;
  Mash HERE
  Sid HERE
  Bob HERE
  ;
RUN;
PROC SORT DATA=forum2;
  BY contact;
RUN;

DATA forum3;
  INPUT contact $ forum3 $;
  CARDS;
  Mash HERE
  Sid HERE
  Jim HERE
  ;
RUN;
PROC SORT DATA=forum3;
  BY contact;
RUN;

PROC SQL NOPRINT;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :n FROM INPUTF;
QUIT;

%MACRO COMBINE(N);
  DATA ALLIN;
    MERGE forum1-forum&n.;
    BY contact;
  RUN;
%MEND COMBINE;

%COMBINE;

PROC PRINT DATA=ALLIN;
```

The code however, works fine when i used a %LET statement as follows:

```
%let n=3;
DATA ALLIN;
  MERGE forum1-forum&n.;
  BY contact;
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=ALLIN;
```

The problem is I won't know how many forums are there, and I prefer that the number be based on the input file.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have other tables in your library that start with the prefix forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro variable scope.

You've created a macro variable `N` that exists in the global table. When you create the macro, it takes a parameter, also called `N` which is local and undefined because you didn't pass a valid parameter.

Call your macro with the created parameter N or move the proc SQL into the macro.

```
%COMBINE(&N);
```

OR

```
%MACRO COMBINE;
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :n FROM INPUTF;
QUIT;


DATA ALLIN;
MERGE forum1-forum&n.;
BY contact;
RUN;

%MEND COMBINE;

%COMBINE;
```

OR

If you only have tables that start with FORUM that you're trying to merge:

```
DATA ALLIN;
MERGE FORUM: ;
BY contact;
RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Reeza, all this is new to me!

Answer (score 0):

So if your dataset InputF has the list of datasets that you want to merge, then put that list into a macro variable. If you always have at least two datasets then no macro logic is required.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select dsn into :dsnlist separated by ' '
  from inputf;
quit;

data allin;
  merge &dsnlist ;
  by contact;
run;
```

To handle the case when you have 0 or 1 dataset name in the list you would need to add macro logic. When there is just one you need to use SET instead of MERGE. You could handle that with the IFC() function.

```
data allin;
  %sysfunc(ifc(1=&sqlobs,set,merge)) &dsnlist ;
  by contact;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question Tom!